# Sublime Text 3 Material Theme not working suddenly

Tags: themes, sublimetext3, color-scheme, material-design

For some reason, my Sublime Text 3 Material Theme stopped working today.  It just shows a white background with an alert popping up repeatedly stating:

```
Error loading colour scheme Packages/Material Theme/schemes/Material-Theme.tmTheme:
Error parsing plist xml: expected = in file Packages/Material
Theme/schemes/Material-Theme.tmTheme on line: 299
```

Any idea what would cause this to happen?  I'm not aware of any possible changes that have been that could result in this.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The same happens to me :( I am running Sublime Text 3 build 3103 on Mac OSX 10.11.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this issue: https://github.com/equinusocio/material-theme/issues/802

It seems this was reported before.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to this.  I had not seen that, and it gives a simple workaround that just involves modifying your sublime-settings file a bit.  Thank you.